# pip install fails with "ValueError: 'format' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable"

Tags: python, pip

When trying to install the python package `progressbar` on OSX El Capitan, I get the following error:

```
Collecting progressbar
  Using cached progressbar-2.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/9s/b1jly7yd0jq639plvkzdvn4m0000gn/T/pip-build-xhfxywsw/progressbar/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import progressbar
      File "/private/var/folders/9s/b1jly7yd0jq639plvkzdvn4m0000gn/T/pip-build-xhfxywsw/progressbar/progressbar/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
        from progressbar.widgets import *
      File "/private/var/folders/9s/b1jly7yd0jq639plvkzdvn4m0000gn/T/pip-build-xhfxywsw/progressbar/progressbar/widgets.py", line 121, in <module>
        class FileTransferSpeed(Widget):
      File "/Users/<USERNAME>/anaconda/lib/python3.4/abc.py", line 133, in __new__
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
    ValueError: 'format' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9s/b1jly7yd0jq639plvkzdvn4m0000gn/T/pip-build-xhfxywsw/progressbar
```

Updating the following did not solve my problem

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade Distribute
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Did you try using - `pip install --no-cache-dir` ?

Comment: This returns     'You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")' Do I maybe have to add more?

Comment: Running 
    'pip install --no-cache-dir progressbar'
returns the same error code 1 as above

Comment: I recon it's not python 3.4 compatible. Installs just fine with python 2.7.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work with python3, however this one does: https://github.com/coagulant/progressbar-python3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The original package does not work with python3, however, there's a fork that does, you can clone it from https://github.com/coagulant/progressbar-python3.git and run

```
python3 setup.py install
```

I dind't, however, check whether the functionality works per se, so YMMV, but it installs at least :)

[edit]

Update by @shadi 30 Jan 2017: [Issue 28](https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar/issues/28) on progressbar's github repo says to use `pip3 install progressbar33`,
thanks!

Comment: Installation works, but progressbar.ProgressBar.update() fails at runtime. I am using Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Comment: @GerhardHagerer Sorry man, as I said in my answer, I didn't check the actual functionality. I'm sorry it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: [Issue 28](https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar/issues/28) on progressbar's github repo says to use `pip3 install progressbar33`

Comment: I used pip3 install progressbar33 but when i installed autosub

    ValueError: 'format' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

Answer (score 1):

I used pip3 install progressbar33 but when i installed autosub

> ValueError: 'format' in slots conflicts with class variable