# ubuntu16.04 cannot install progreebar for python

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I tried to install progressbar for python3.5, I met an error:

I use 
sudo pip install progressbar

It shows:

```
Collecting progressbar
```

Downloading progressbar-2.3.tar.gz

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ktnxhtii/progressbar/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import progressbar
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ktnxhtii/progressbar/progressbar/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from progressbar.widgets import *
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ktnxhtii/progressbar/progressbar/widgets.py", line 121, in <module>
    class FileTransferSpeed(Widget):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 133, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
ValueError: 'format' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ktnxhtii/progressbar/

I don't know how to handle this problem. Please give me some advice,thanks in advance.

Comment: What's more in detail, it shows error in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "ValueError: 'format' in \_\_slots\_\_ conflicts with class variable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063427/pip-install-fails-with-valueerror-format-in-slots-conflicts-with-class-v)