# installing progressbar Python package

Tags: python, progress-bar

I get this error:

```
E:\opensource_codes\semi-auto-anno\src>pip install progressbar
Collecting progressbar
  Downloading progressbar-2.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0_37al8d\progressbar\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import progressbar
      File "C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0_37al8d\progressbar\progressbar\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
        from progressbar.widgets import *
      File "C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0_37al8d\progressbar\progressbar\widgets.py", line 121, in <module>
        class FileTransferSpeed(Widget):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\abc.py", line 133, in __new__
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
    ValueError: 'format' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0_37al8d\progressbar\
```

and I have:

```
E:\opensource_codes\semi-auto-anno\src>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

how should I install progressbar for Python 3.6.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "ValueError: 'format' in \_\_slots\_\_ conflicts with class variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063427/pip-install-fails-with-valueerror-format-in-slots-conflicts-with-class-v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best method, but it works for me:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/coagulant/progressbar-python3.git
Cloning into 'progressbar-python3'...
remote: Counting objects: 30, done.
remote: Total 30 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 30
Unpacking objects: 100% (30/30), done.

mona6@DESKTOP-0JQ770H MINGW64 /e/opensource_codes
$ ls
cnpy/        depth-masking-src/     gesture_recognition/  semi-auto-anno/
cnpy_cmake/  depth-masking-src.zip  progressbar-python3/

mona6@DESKTOP-0JQ770H MINGW64 /e/opensource_codes
$ cd progressbar-python3/

mona6@DESKTOP-0JQ770H MINGW64 /e/opensource_codes/progressbar-python3 (master)
$ ls
ChangeLog.yaml  LICENSE.txt  progressbar/  README.txt  tox.ini
examples.py*    MANIFEST.in  README.md     setup.py*

E:\opensource_codes\progressbar-python3>python setup.py install
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\dist.py:331: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.3dev' to '2.3.dev0'
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating progressbar.egg-info
writing progressbar.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to progressbar.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to progressbar.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'progressbar.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'progressbar.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'progressbar.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\progressbar
copying progressbar\compat.py -> build\lib\progressbar
copying progressbar\progressbar.py -> build\lib\progressbar
copying progressbar\widgets.py -> build\lib\progressbar
copying progressbar\__init__.py -> build\lib\progressbar
creating build\bdist.win-amd64
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar
copying build\lib\progressbar\compat.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar
copying build\lib\progressbar\progressbar.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar
copying build\lib\progressbar\widgets.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar
copying build\lib\progressbar\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar\compat.py to compat.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar\progressbar.py to progressbar.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar\widgets.py to widgets.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\progressbar\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying progressbar.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying progressbar.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying progressbar.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying progressbar.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist\progressbar-2.3.dev0-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing progressbar-2.3.dev0-py3.6.egg
Copying progressbar-2.3.dev0-py3.6.egg to c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Adding progressbar 2.3.dev0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\progressbar-2.3.dev0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for progressbar==2.3.dev0
Finished processing dependencies for progressbar==2.3.dev0

E:\opensource_codes\progressbar-python3>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import progressbar
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
conda install progressbar2
```

or maybe

```
pip install progressbar2
```

Comment: Works for me, even though the original error was: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'progressbar'`, not `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'progressbar2'` lol

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same issue when trying to implement the progressbar for a code. Above suggestion : `conda install progressbar2` still holds good.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user8> conda install progressbar2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - progressbar2


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    progressbar2-4.2.0         |   py39haa95532_0          52 KB
    python-utils-3.3.3         |   py39haa95532_0          36 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:          88 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  progressbar2       pkgs/main/win-64::progressbar2-4.2.0-py39haa95532_0 None
  python-utils       pkgs/main/win-64::python-utils-3.3.3-py39haa95532_0 None


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
python-utils-3.3.3   | 36 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
progressbar2-4.2.0   | 52 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
```

In case you IDE does not identify the installation, restart and retry. You may install this package in your Virtual environment separately in case you are using one.

The import in your program however, does not change. It still remains :

```
import progressbar
```